# Change password in cakephp 2x

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.1

I'm trying to make a simple password reset function that allows an administrator to change a users password and email them the new password. Everything works except the password never actually gets changed in the database. I found a lot of information about this topic but nothing has worked. Why is the password not being changed? I'm using Cakephp 2.1

I tried this:

```
public function auto_reset_password($id = null){
    $this->User->id = $id;
    $randomPass= $this->User->generatePassword();
    $randomPassHashed= $this->Auth->password($randomPass);
    $this->User->set('password', $randomPassHashed);
    $this->User->save();
    //email code....
}
```

and substituting this:

```
$u = $this->User->find('first', array(
    'conditions' => array('User.id' => $id)
));
//.....
$u['User']['password'] = $randomPassHashed;
```

My user modal has this beforeSave:

```
public function beforeSave() {
    if (isset($this->data[$this->alias]['password'])) {
        $this->data[$this->alias]['password'] = AuthComponent::password($this->data[$this->alias]['password']);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Try to avoid hashing it twice (which you are doing here via manual hash call and via beforeSave() callback). This might help as well: [Working with passwords in CakePHP](http://www.dereuromark.de/2011/08/25/working-with-passwords-in-cakephp/)

Comment: Add the UserModel, so we can take a look.

Comment: I got rid of the first password hash and set the password with the unhashed value, but nothing has changed... What are you looking for in the User Model? I can't find any other code that relates to this in that file. The generate password function definitely works.

Answer (score 0):

A few things to look out for:

- in the database the "password" field should be named the same, otherwise it will not be saved
- `$this->User->save()` will try to *validate your data* before saving. Validation may fail if you have defined rules for not empty email or not empty username and so on. You really need to look at the result that save returns! (or you can disable validation like this `$this->User->save( null, false )`)
- use saveField() instead: `$this->User->saveField( 'password', $randomPassHashed );`
- make sure you're not double hashing as you do in the original question.